# Getting an extra list of voices in chrome speechSynthesis

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-chrome

I tried using Google `speechSythesis` (Web Speech API) and the voices it gives me are fewer than the voice I expected. In chrome, I had 22 voices but in other browsers, I had 3 voices, Is there any way I can increase the number of voices

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function test(){
                console.log(window.speechSynthesis.getVoices())
            }

            const getVoices = () => {};

            getVoices();
            if(window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
            window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = getVoices;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="test()">Test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe different browsers will includes different voices in addition to compatible voices that are installed on your operating system

it looks to me like browsers are supposed to make available the voices your operating system has installed, and in addition can also provide their own browser voices